# Using layers attribute within QgsPropertyOverrideButton

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

In addition to [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350036/receiving-value-from-qgspropertyoverridebutton-if-data-defined-override-is-check), I am struggling to implement the possibility to choose an attribute from a layer within QgsPropertyOverrideButton.

I have a combobox where one can choose a layer to use. Getting attributes and geometries from this selected layer works just fine, but it is not recognized by QgsPropertyOverrideButton when I use `.setVectorLayer()` [as described in docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyOverrideButton.html#a310fe568a5be2575358b7574add78172). For example `self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.setVectorLayer(selectedLayer)`

[image]

A reduced code snipped:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children() # Fetch the currently loaded layers
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.Isochrones_SelectInputLayer.currentIndex() # Fetch the selected layer in combobox
selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex].layer() # Use the in combobox selected layer
fieldnames = [field.name() for field in selectedLayer.fields()] # Receive fieldnames from selected layer
features = selectedLayer.getFeatures() # <-- Works just fine

self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.setVectorLayer(selectedLayer) # <-- Seems to not work
self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.updateFieldLists()   # <-- Seems to not work

# Do some stuff here     

for feature in features:
    # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes
    print("Feature ID: ", feature.id())
    # fetch geometry
    # show some information about the feature geometry
    geom = feature.geometry()
    pointgeom = geom.asPoint() #Read Point geometry
    x = pointgeom.x() #Read X-Value
    y = pointgeom.y() #Read Y-Value
    print("PointX: ", x, " | PointY: ", y)

    # fetch attributes
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
    print(attrs)

    #Check where to gather attributes from: GUI or Layer?
    #WalkSpeed
    if self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.isActive() == True:
        Isochrones_WalkSpeed, IrrelevantSuccessStorage = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.toProperty().value(QgsExpressionContext()) #Receiving Value from GUI: DataDefinedOverride
    else:
        Isochrones_WalkSpeed = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed.value() #Receiving Value from GUI: SpinBox

    # Do more stuff here
```

Why does `.getFeatures()` recognize the layer but `.setVectorLayer()` doesnt? And how would I need to write my code to make `.setVectorLayer()` recognizing the selected layer, so users are able to choose an attribute from the selected layer within QgsPropertyOverrideButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need several things to correctly use your `QgsPropertyOverrideButton`.

### Initializing the button

- First, you may want to register an expression context generator, which will allow the use of global, project, and layer variables. `QgsVectorLayer` is a `QgsExpressionContextGenerator`, so you just have to call

```
self.dlg.overrideButton.registerExpressionContextGenerator(selectedLayer)
```

- Then, you need to tell the button which kind of property it expects. This is done by calling the [`init`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyOverrideButton.html#a36eb2e7a7defab5f26a6bd144f52aeac) function of the button. This function expects a `QgsPropertyDefinition`, which you can create like this:

```
definition = QgsPropertyDefinition("walkSpeed", "Walk Speed km/h", QgsPropertyDefinition.DoublePositive) 
self.dlg.overrideButton.init(0, QgsProperty(), definition, layer, False)
```

This tells the button to accept any value that can be cast to a positive floating number. It also removes the need to call `setVectorLayer`. For other type of definitions, see the [official documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyDefinition.html#a780c10d9241052f1be74e9759436abfc).

The `QgsPropertyOverrideButton` is now all set.

---

### Resolving the expression

Next, when you evaluate the property for each feature, you have to correctly initialize the `QgsExpressionContext`. If you don't, you will be able to evaluate simple numerical expressions, but nothing which involves layer variables or feature fields.

QGIS provides a `QgsExpressionContextUtils` class which can be used to generate expression contexts. The following context will be able to evaluate global, project, and layer variables:

```
ctx = QgsExpressionContext(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(selectedLayer))
```

Aditionnaly, you need to set the context's feature before each call to `toProperty`, which will allow the button to use the correct feature when evaluating the expression.

```
ctx = QgsExpressionContext(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(selectedLayer))
for feature in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
    ctx.setFeature(feature)
    walkSpeed, ok = self.dlg.overrideButton.toProperty().value(ctx)  # Receiving value from DataDefinedOverride
    if not ok:
        walkSpeed = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed.value()  # Receiving value from spinBox
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `currentText()` method to fetch the selected layer in the combo box.

```
layers = project.layerTreeRoot().children()
selectedLayerName = self.dlg.Isochrones_SelectInputLayer.currentText()
selectedLayer = [l.layer() for l in layers if l.name() == selectedLayerName][0]
self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.setVectorLayer(selectedLayer)
```

Having said that (and you probably don't want to start reworking your plugin), but I would strongly recommend using a `QgsMapLayerComboBox` custom widget for selecting input layers rather than a generic `QComboBox`. Once you start playing around with them they are much easier to work with!

I wrote about them in an answer here:

[Listing of vector layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339394/listing-of-vector-layers/339422#339422)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't make it work like this. But could be just me... +1 for the great tip about QgsMapLayerComboBox, helped a lot.